# How to merge queries

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am writing a page where a list of Blog posts are rendered, with pagination. I am using GORM with Go 1.12.
Each blogpost has an author called User, and that user could contain some additional employee info if necessary. (e.g. intro, function title, ...)

My models:

```
type EmployeeInfo struct {
    UserID    uint   `gorm:"not null;unique"`
    Title     string `gorm:"not null"`
    Intro     string `gorm:""`
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model

    Username  string    `gorm:"unique;not null"`
    Password  string    `gorm:"unique;not null"`

    FirstName string    `gorm:"not null"`
    LastName  string    `gorm:"not null"`

    Company   Company   `gorm:"not null"`

    Role      string    `gorm:"not null;default:user"`
}

type BlogPost struct {
    gorm.Model

    Title     string    `gorm:"not null"`
    Slug      string    `gorm:"unique;not null;index"`
    Intro     string    `gorm:"not null"`
    Text      string    `gorm:"not null"`
    Category  string    `gorm:"not null"`
    PictureUrl string   `gorm:"not null"`
    Author    User      `gorm:"not null"`
    AuthorID  uint      `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

My code currenty looks like this:

```
func (hh *BlogIndexHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // set desired language
    language.SetLanguage(r)

    // set title
    hh.data.Title = fmt.Sprintf(
        "%s - %s",
        language.Translate("blog", nil, false),
        language.Translate("product", nil, false),
    )

    // get current page
    hh.data.Page = 0
    if intPage, err := strconv.Atoi(r.URL.Query().Get(pageQueryName)); err != nil && intPage >= 0 {
        hh.data.Page = intPage
    }

    // get max page number
    hh.data.MaxPage = 1
    var totalPosts int
    if err := hh.database.Model(&models.BlogPost{}).Count(&totalPosts).Error; err != nil {
        totalPosts = 1
    } else {
        hh.data.MaxPage = roundUp(float64(totalPosts / PostsPerPage))
    }

    // if page > maxPage, set it right
    if hh.data.Page > hh.data.MaxPage {
        hh.data.Page = hh.data.MaxPage
    }

    // fetch blog posts
    if err := hh.database.
        Preload("Author").
        Order("created_at DESC").
        Offset(PostsPerPage * hh.data.Page).
        Limit(PostsPerPage).
        Find(&hh.data.Posts).
        Error; err != nil {

        log.Errorf(appengine.NewContext(r), "could not get posts: %v", err)
    }

    // set cacheable
    system.SetCacheable(w, system.CacheTime1Day)

    // send webpage
    hh.template.Render("blog/index", w, hh.data)
}
```

However, a request fires 3 different queries:

```
[2019-03-11 19:51:52]  [29.55ms]  SELECT count(*) FROM "blog_posts"  WHERE "blog_posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL
[0 rows affected or returned ]

[2019-03-11 19:51:52]  [27.50ms]  SELECT * FROM "blog_posts"  WHERE "blog_posts"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 9 OFFSET 0
[1 rows affected or returned ]

[2019-03-11 19:51:52]  [49.86ms]  SELECT * FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND (("id" IN ('58')))
```

Is there a way to merge these with GORM?
I'd like to optimize these, like I would with a manual query.

Answer (score 0):

GORM does not support database level `JOIN` on `Preload`. You have two choices:

- either use `Preload` and live with the fact that it executes an extra query to fetch related data (which should not be a problem unless you have a heavy load on your server)
- or you can write your own [Raw Sql](http://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html) query using `JOIN` and handle everything in one query, then map the data to a struct.

Comment: That's really a shame, even if I need to manually map it. Not even for the COUNT(*) ?

Comment: What do you mean by `Not even for the COUNT(*)` ? How would you optimize `count` even if you write raw sql?

Comment: I mean not having to issue a separate query to calculate a `COUNT(*) OVER()`